# APPLICATION PATH in Zend Framework getting appended to virtual host name

Tags: php, zend-framework, path, relative-path

In my Layout, when I do this

```
<?php $js = APPLICATION_PATH."/../public/js"; ?>
<script src = <?php echo $js."/signup_layout_js.js"; ?> ></script>
```

I get a js error

```
http://proj_name/home/aman/Work/proj_name/public/js/signup_layout_js.js
```

My APPLICTION_PATH is getting appended to `http://proj_name/`, I dont want that.

But if I do this, it works fine on `http://proj_name/` but breaks when i go to a controller/action like `http://proj_name/Controller/Action`

```
<script src ="./js/signup_layout_js.js"></script>
```

How can I correct this. Thanks.

Also in my index.php, APPLICATION_PATH is

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));
```

Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link scripts like this:

```
<script src = "<?= $this->baseUrl() . '/js/signup_layout_js.js' ?>" ></script>
```

Or use headScript helper:

```
//put this in header
<?= $this->headScript(); ?>

//put this before closing body tag
<?= $this->inlineScript() ?>

//and this anywhere in you code ($this is view object)
$this->headScript()
    ->prependFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js')
    ->appendFile($this->baseUrl() . '/js/flying-header.js')
    ->appendScript('
                    var google_conversion_id = 9999999;
                    var google_custom_params = window.google_tag_params;
                    var google_remarketing_only = true;');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire path is part of the src for your scripts because you are prepending it. Try echoing the value of your `APPLICATION_PATH` constant. This is not the correct behaviour for referencing static files in web applications.

In your case, you should look into using Zend Framework's built-in `headScript` and `inlineScript` view helpers for this. You shouldn't need to write the `script` DOM tags yourself.